# What is ArcGIS's lightest-weight data type for web mapping apps to minimize network io?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am wanting to move geometries/attributes to and from arcgis server and web client.  If, I've already thought through my network io vs app architecture and have concluded with architecture Z (really I just have enough time to optimize where easiest!..low hanging fruit!)

My specific use case is in regard to handling feature records varyingly based on attributes which would be boolean.  I will either put 1 or 0 in certain fields and do something useful for each of these?  If I am doing field creation via a dbf template on ArcGIS Server with python, what should my boolean fields be if I want to minimize traffic?  Text with 1 of Length 1 or Short of Precision 1 or other?

Please provide some explanation/link to help or other.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ArcSDE? If so, take a look at this: http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/schemaobjects/schemaobjects.htm#Stream and this: http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/schemaobjects/schemaobjects.htm . They are the ArcSDE API in C (Java also available). It really depends on the machines involved and/or the database backend (MS SQL, Postgre, etc) and how they represent those data types. Typically char is represented as 8 bytes, and an int as 32 bytes...but it is also dependent on the system/database. Any info on your architecture?

Comment: If I think of anything else I'll post an answer, but for example: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/A_comparison_of_ArcGIS_ArcSDE_and_SQL_Server_data_types/002q00000068000000/ ... And more generally browse the Geodatabases and ArcSDE section: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Welcome_to_the_ArcGIS_Server_10_Help/009300000004000000/

Comment: Yeah, I figured I would have to dig in and see what specifics would apply.  Thanks guys.  I'm using a shapefile served over ArcGIS Server on windows server 2008.  I may move to sql server 2008 if editing is needed.

Comment: What is the database backend? SDE + ???

Comment: If I move need to edit over the web, I will move it to sql server 2008 and arcgis server/sde 2010.  Right now it is a shapefile.

Comment: Then the shapefile will be represented as a feature set.

Comment: Yep. From ArcGIS Server..a feature set passed to a silverlight client and pushed into a graphics layer.